# PHP check if string contain substrings (batch)

Tags: php, regex, string, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if (stripos($jml['JENIS_TOKO'],'buah') !== false || stripos($jml['JENIS_TOKO'],'bakery') !== false || stripos($jml['JENIS_TOKO'],'roti') !== false) {
```

Is there any way to shorten this `if` condition in PHP? Just like `WHERE JENIS_TOKO REGEXP 'buah|bakery|roti'` in SQL.

It's really not a problem if it just 3 like in my example, but I know it won't be effective & the code becomes too long if my substrings is ten or more. (ps: I don't know about regex, but I'm sure that's the clue)

**EDIT:**
This is not a possible duplicate as alleged. I already check reffered question and see the approved answer, but my case is different. I use bunch of strings, not an array, thus I don't want to use array & `foreach` loop *unless that is the only way*.

I already explain: "Just like `WHERE JENIS_TOKO REGEXP 'buah|bakery|roti'`" so I'm sure there's a way to solve this with a regular expression method in single line.

Comment: preg_match() would be shorter

Comment: @rtfm yeah I know that will, but I need the answer with example to solve my case, because I don't understand about regular expression yet. then I will learn from the answer. thank you.

Comment: manual page has great examples

Comment: @Pyromonk so the array & `foreach` loop is the solution? not `preg_match` or any regular expression within single line? :/

Comment: @rtfm okay, thank you for the directions.

Comment: `if(preg_match("#\b(buah|bakery|roti)\b#",$jml['JENIS_TOKO'])){` https://ideone.com/XChMCJ

Comment: Try with: `if(preg_match('#(buah|bakery|roti)#i', $jml['JENIS_TOKO']) === 1) { ... }`

Comment: @evitt done, it works! I was just learn a bit about `preg_match` and the validity is indeed use `=== 1`. thank you so much :)